# Android: how to use content provider to attach file from url to email intent

Tags: android, email, attachment, provider

When i click send email in my activity file from url is displayed like attached, however file is never received, only email body and subject.

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                        intent.setType("*/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file " + title);

                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"some_email@email.com"});
                        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(trackUrl)));

                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
                }
        });
```

Here is my project https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-91m-6ZevwCRTYtYXRGb3l6UVE/edit?usp=sharing and here's my activity code:  http://pastebin.com/uzdJYxab. The task i had received states that

> ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE would use external activity which should access sound file. To allow such access you need: - Create ContentProvider. - Override public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)

However there's little to no info on how to use content provider and it's method ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) in order to attach a file from url as email attachment. Can someone at least point me out in correct direction?

Comment: you need to make sure that your uri has "file://" in front of it.

Comment: i just checked logcat and i got: file:///http%3A/wbads.vo.llnwd.net/o25/u/wbdd/vapp/thedarkknight/soundboard/German/TDK_Joker_here_we_go_GER.mp3%20, so i guess it is parsed correctly however file is never received as attached

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is very old, but in the event that someone else stumbles across this question:

"file://" URIs may not work, depending on if the other app has access to the specific file.  It's unlikely to work if you're referencing a file that's [MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) (and [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) was deprecated in API 17).

Google provides a [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) in their v4 Support Library.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) is very informative on how to configure it.

They also have a training called [Sharing Files](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) that provides a walk-through explanation.